# Why isn't -moz-animation working?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

The following CSS works fine in Webkit. Haven't checked it in Opera, but I know it's not working in Firefox. Can anybody tell me why?

The correct classes are definitely getting applied to my HTML (inspected it with Firebug, and I do see the `-moz-animation: 500ms ease 0s normal forwards 1 arrowRotateDot` property on `.arrow`).

This also doesn't work in IE9, although I did originally have `-ms-animation:...` and `-ms-transform:...`. I thought it was supposed to work in IE9, but when it didn't I just assumed that IE didn't support these yet. However, now that it's not working in Firefox, maybe something else is going on.

```
.page.updatesPodcasts > .mainContent > .content .contentUpdates .disc.dot .dvd .arrow {
  -webkit-animation: arrowRotateDot 500ms forwards;
  -moz-animation: arrowRotateDot 500ms forwards;
  -o-animation: arrowRotateDot 500ms forwards;
  animation: arrowRotateDot 500ms forwards;
}
.page.updatesPodcasts > .mainContent > .content .contentUpdates .disc.f2 .dvd .arrow {
  -webkit-animation: arrowRotateF2 500ms forwards;
  -moz-animation: arrowRotateF2 500ms forwards;
  -o-animation: arrowRotateF2 500ms forwards;
  animation: arrowRotateF2 500ms forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowRotateDot {
  100%  {
      left:-18px; top:182px;
      -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      }
}
@-webkit-keyframes arrowRotateF2 {
  0%  {
      left:-18px; top:182px;
      -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      transform: scale(1) rotate(-30deg);
      }
  100%  {
      left:115px; top:257px;
      -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(-90deg);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(-90deg);
      transform: scale(1) rotate(-90deg);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your animations are not working in Firefox because you are using @-**webkit**-keyframes, which only applies to Webkit browsers, i.e. Chrome and Safari. The (somewhat) cross-browser way to do animation keyframes is:

```
@keyframes animationName {
    /* animation rules */
}

@-moz-keyframes animationName {
    /* -moz-animation rules */
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationName {
    /* -webkit-animation rules */
}
```

Opera and Internet Explorer do not currently support the @keyframes rule.

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 supports `@keyframes` rule. (without using `-ms-` prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Skyline is correct. Firefox does not support this, so you will need additional code to get the same or similar effects if they exist without webkit.

Also, here is some additional information that might help you with your code or help you in deciding where to go from this point with your code if adding additional code is not an option (I ended up changing how I code to keep from being overwhelmed with code):

http://caniuse.com/#

http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html