# Text flickers during animation on firefox

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to do slide animation using CSS and Angular Js. I am upto this :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/ev2d2a2t/9/)
On chrome this animation works flawless. But on Firefox text shakes and flickers little bit when animation goes on.I am not able to figure out exact issue . Any idea  ..

Code :

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="animationCtrl">
  <ul class='list'>
    <li>
        <div class="slide-animation">
            <div class="slide-animation-wrap new-slide-wrap {{cssTimeInfo1}}"> <span class="text">{{valueSet1[0]}}</span>

                <label class="small-label">{{valueSet2[1]}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-animation-wrap old-slide-wrap {{cssTimeInfo1}}"> <span class="text">{{valueSet1[1]}}</span>

                <label class="small-label">{{valueSet2[1]}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.list > li {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
  height: 72px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1.06%;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3) inset;
}

.small-label {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.714em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #999999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.286em;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
}



/* Slide animation */
.slide-animation {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.slide-animation-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide-animation-wrap.new-slide-wrap {
  top: -45px;
}
.slide-animation-wrap.old-slide-wrap {
  top: -51px;
}
.slide-animation-wrap.slide-in-animation,
.slide-animation-wrap.slide-out-animation {
  -webkit-animation: slide-outside-animation 1s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: slide-outside-animation 1s linear forwards;
  animation: slide-outside-animation 1s linear forwards;
}
.slide-animation-wrap:before,
.slide-animation-wrap:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.slide-animation-wrap:after {
  clear: both;
}
.slide-animation-wrap:before,
.slide-animation-wrap:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.slide-animation-wrap:after {
  clear: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-outside-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
    transform: translateY(45px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-outside-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
    transform: translateY(45px);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes slide-outside-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
    transform: translateY(45px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-outside-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
    transform: translateY(45px);
  }
}
```

Angular :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('animationCtrl', ['$scope','$interval', function ($scope,$interval) {
    $scope.valueSet1=['HGFhgfsffghfhgf','HGFhgfsffghfhgf'];
    $scope.valueSet2=['ABC','ABC'];
    $scope.cssTimeInfo1 = "display-none";
    $scope.cssTimeInfo2 = "display-none";
    var flag=0;
    $interval(function(){
        //0
        $scope.cssTimeInfo1='slide-in-animation';
        $scope.cssTimeInfo2 = "display-none";
        flag++;
       if(flag>1){
           flag=0;
           //0

           $scope.cssTimeInfo1 = " ";
           $scope.cssTimeInfo2 = " ";

       }
        else{
           //1

           $scope.cssTimeInfo1 = "slide-out-animation";
           $scope.cssTimeInfo2 = "slide-in-animation";
       }
    },1000);

}]);
```

Comment: It's working fine here.

Comment: @ketan :Have you seen it on Firefox ?

Comment: Yes. And it's working fine. no flickers.  I am using latest version of firefox.

Comment: watch it closely .. while text slides down .. it becomes faint and dark..

Comment: I m also on latest version :(

Comment: try to see if adding `-moz-transform` and `-moz-animation` will make animation works properly in your Firefox version : check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135805/equivalent-of-webkit-transform-in-mozilla-firefox) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615243/why-isnt-moz-animation-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a text flickering issue on Firefox with transforms. Adding

`backface-visibility: hidden;`

to the transformed element fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding:

```
will-change: transform;
```

on the element being transformed.

> Provides a rendering hint to the user agent, stating what kinds of changes the author expects to perform on the element.
>
> (Firefox 36, Safari 9, Chrome 36, Opera 24)

See [MDN reference (link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) for more information.

**Note** (from the MDN reference): *will-change* is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems.